# How to access the negotiated response content-type in ASP.NET Core 2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

How can I access the negotiated content-type (after the content negotiation) inside a controller action?

[It seems that in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/content-negotiation#how-content-negotiation-works) you could access a ContentNegotiationResult object with the chosen formatter and the negotiated content-type.

Is there an equivalent in ASP.NET Core 2?